# Dar Selected em determinado valor recebido na função JS

Tags: php, javascript

```
> function
> editar_etapa_projeto(etapa_projeto_id,etapa_id,dias_total,data_inicial){
>     $('#etapa_projeto_id').val(etapa_projeto_id);
>     $('#etapa_id').find('option[value='+etapa_id+']').attr('selected',true');
>     $('#dias_total').val(dias_total);
>     $('#data_inicial').val(data_inicial); }
```

Eu quero com essa função Javascript, que ele preencha os inputs de ids # tal com os valores recebidos por variaveis de entrada na funcao.

Está funcionando para os inputs, ele pega o valor da variavel, e joga no value do input.

Mas no select não,

eu preciso que ele verifique o valor que está recebido na variavel etapa_id, vá até o select de id #etapa_id, e de um selected na opção do select onde aquele valor está.

```
$('#etapa_id').find('option[value='+etapa_id+']').attr('selected’,'true');
```

Descobri que ele seleciona sim, mas por erro no firefox de compatibilidade ao selected="selected", não vai.

Comment: Tens uma aspa simples a mais, depois de `true` e tipos de aspas diferentes... Testa com `.attr('selected', true);`

Comment: Pelo que sei, é a mesma regra para pegar valor do select, se ele estiver selecionado, conforme a resposta do @KaduAmaral.

Comment: Está levando mas não seleciona o .val

Answer (score 4):

Use o `val` semelhante aos inputs:

```
$('#etapa_id').val(etapa_id);
```

Exemplo:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.setval', function(event){
 var etapa_id = $(this).data('val');
  
  $('#etapa_id').val(etapa_id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="etapa_id">
  <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
  <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
  <option value="3">Valor 3</option>
  <option value="4">Valor 4</option>
  <option value="5">Valor 5</option>
</select><br><br>

<button class="setval" data-val="1">Setar Valor 1</button><br>
<button class="setval" data-val="2">Setar Valor 2</button><br>
<button class="setval" data-val="3">Setar Valor 3</button><br>
<button class="setval" data-val="4">Setar Valor 4</button><br>
<button class="setval" data-val="5">Setar Valor 5</button><br>
```

#### [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v3c61uca/)

Comment: Não quero pegar o valor do select, quero levar um valor já existente sem adicionar um novo para ele e deixar selecionado já, este não seleciona

Comment: Se existir um `option`  com o `value` igual ao valor da variável `etapa_id` no `select#etapa_id` a expressão da resposta irá setar o `option` como `selected`: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v3c61uca/)

Comment: @AndréSilveiraMachado o método `val` do jQuery, quando você não passa um parâmetro `val()` ele retorna o valor do elemento, quando você passa `val("algumvalor")` ele seta o valor do elemento. [Mais detalhes na documentação](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Answer (score 0):

Faltou `"`, veja como deveria ser:

```
var el, valor;
el = $('#etapa_id').find('option[value="'+etapa_id+'"]')
el.attr('selected’,true');
valor = $('#etapa_id').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Fazendo assim, já irá funcionar:

```
    function editarEtapaProjeto(data) {
        for (var i in data) {
             $('#'+data[i][0]).val(data[i][1]);
        }
    }

    var data = [
                {'etapa_projeto_id', 1},
                {'etapa_id', 2},
                {'dias_total', 10},
                {'data_inicial', '2015-10-10 20:00:00'}
               ];
     editarEtapaProjeto(data);
```

**Obs:** eu reformatei o código para seguir um padrão de formatação.

Answer (score 0):

Faltava atualizar o select para o firefox funcionar

```
    $('#etapa_id').selectmenu({ });
```